# Critical update not activated but is past the Auto activation date and no Activate button is available

Tags: access, critical-update, aura-enabled

[image: Critical update]
In my dev org, these two critical updates haven't been activated by admins within the Auto activation date. So as per salesforce, shouldn't this be activated automatically? As the screenshot reads they are not activated and Activation button not available as well. Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 1):

In layman's terms: Salesforce is still "getting around to it", so to speak.

In more detailed terms:

> Auto-Activation Dates for Critical Updates are targets and subject to
> change.  If an Auto-Activation Date is in the past, it typically means
> the updates will be activated automatically during the next major
> release.

Documentation:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000350925&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1

Comment: But as a precaution, if we were to activate ourselves manually to make necessary changes before it hits the production, should we raise a support ticket with salesforce?

Comment: The docs don't say.  I'll bet the support team doesn't have a mechanism to speed up the release team's patch enablement.  But there's no harm in asking.  Just raise a support case and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

To activate critical update, you can follow the below steps

1. Go to setup menu> search for "Release updates(Beta)"
2. Search for the critical update you are looking to activate like "Restrict Access to @AuraEnabled Apex Methods for Authenticated Users Based on User Profile" with "Test run supported" indicated on it.
3. click on "Get Started" and then on "enable test run"

Note: This critical update will be automatically enforced in: Winter '21 (Related: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lc_restrict_apex_authenticated_users.htm)